# Ajax filter button display all posts

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, filters, ajax

I created a loop for my Custom Posts Type `workshop` with two custom taxonomies `group` and `teacher` on the same page. The Ajax filter works perfectly thanks to the solution provided [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/383666/ajax-filter-with-custom-taxonomies). The user can select one taxonomy or both to display the posts.

Each links of the filter works with a `<input type="radio"...>`, for both taxonomies lists. What I'm trying to achieve is to create a button `.filter-reset` which resets all the radio inputs and displays all the posts of my Custom Posts Type.

The issue is when I click the button, it returns "No posts found".

Here is the PHP code for the filter in the frontend:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter" class="form-filter">
   <div class="container">
   <?php

   if( $terms = get_terms( 'group', 'orderby=name&exclude=-1' ) ) :
    echo '<div class="filter-tax filter--group">';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
      echo '<input class="btn-radio" type="radio" name="categoryfilter1" value="' . $term->term_id . '"><label>' . $term->name . '</label>';
    endforeach;
    echo '</div>';
   endif;

   if( $terms = get_terms( 'teacher', 'orderby=name&exclude=-1' ) ) :
     echo '<div class="filter-tax filter--teacher">';
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
       echo '<input class="btn-radio" type="radio" name="categoryfilter2" value="' . $term->term_id . '"><label>' . $term->name . '</label>';
     endforeach;
     echo '</div>';
    endif;

    ?>

    <a href="#" class="filter-reset">View all</a>

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">
  </div>
</form>
```

The PHP code for the AJAX filter in my functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'mysite_filter_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'mysite_filter_function');

function mysite_filter_function(){

   $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
   );

   if (isset($_POST['categoryfilter1']) && isset($_POST['categoryfilter2'])) {

        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'group',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter1']
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'teacher',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter2']
            ),
        );

   } elseif (isset($_POST['categoryfilter1']) && !isset($_POST['categoryfilter2'])) {

        $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'group',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter1']
        )
        );

   } elseif (!isset($_POST['categoryfilter1']) && isset($_POST['categoryfilter2'])) {

        $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'teacher',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter2']
        )
        );

   }

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-archive' );
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
        echo 'No posts found';
    endif;

    die();
}
```

The JS code:

```
$('#filter').change(function(){
    var filter = $('#filter');
    $.ajax({
        url:filter.attr('action'),
        data:filter.serialize(),
        type:filter.attr('method'),
        beforeSend:function(xhr){
            //filter.find('button').text('Processing...');
        },
        success:function(data){
            //filter.find('button').text('Filter');
            $('.loop-archive').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});

$(".filter-reset").click(function() {
    document.getElementById('filter').reset();
    $('.loop-archive-workshop').append();

    var filter = $('#filter');

    $.ajax({
        url:filter.attr('action'),
        type:filter.attr('method'),
        data:filter.serialize(),
        success:function(data){
            $('.loop-archive').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Thank you.

> EDIT

Here is the log.txt when I click the reset button:

```
Array
(
    [action] => myfilter
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by what @JacobPeattie said, that they are still set but empty you need to change the conditional login to check for empty.

In our previous discussion I wrote this conditions

```
if ((isset($_POST['categoryfilter1']) && !empty($_POST['categoryfilter1'])) && (isset($_POST['categoryfilter2']) && !empty($_POST['categoryfilter2']))) {
    // both properties are set and have value (not empty)
} elseif ((isset($_POST['categoryfilter1']) && !empty($_POST['categoryfilter1'])) && (!isset($_POST['categoryfilter2']) || empty($_POST['categoryfilter2']))) {
    // only categoryfilter1 is set and has value and categoryfilter2 is either not set or set but has no value
} elseif ((!isset($_POST['categoryfilter1']) || empty($_POST['categoryfilter1'])) && (isset($_POST['categoryfilter2']) && !empty($_POST['categoryfilter2']))) {
    // only categoryfilter2 is set and has value and categoryfilter1 is either not set or set but has no value
}
```

Try using it and see if it helps

> EDIT

I dont know what post type you want to get but try adding it to the $args as well.

So you initial $args will look like this

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    // 'post_status' => 'publish', // this is optional, this will get only published posts
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
```

I think that this creates the problem

Comment: I tried it after reading @JacobPeattie's answer and unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Lets try the error log again, after clicking the reset button what $_POST contains, update your question with that content

Comment: If you're interested to have a look, I also opened a third thread with Ajax Filter with checkboxes. I'm building various prototypes for different projects. Here is the [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/383695/filter-posts-with-ajax-form-and-checkboxes)

Comment: The question is updated with the log.txt

Comment: The `if` conditions are find, seems like a problem with `$args`, updated my answer

Comment: You find it! I can't believe I didn't try it before... Sometimes it's good having someone checking the code with a new eye. Thanks again @Buttered_Toast.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is using `isset()` for the conditions:

```
isset($_POST['categoryfilter1']) && isset($_POST['categoryfilter2'])
```

Because those inputs are still part of the form their post variables will still be *set*, they'll just be empty. Using `!empty()` and `empty()` would be the way to go:

```
if (isset($_POST['categoryfilter1']) && isset($_POST['categoryfilter2'])) {
    // etc.
} elseif (!empty($_POST['categoryfilter1']) && empty($_POST['categoryfilter2'])) {
    // etc.
} elseif (empty($_POST['categoryfilter1']) && !empty($_POST['categoryfilter2'])) {
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie. I changed the conditional to `!empty()` and `empty()`but it is still not working.